Why does decoding a *.jpeg encoded frame using nvJPEG add so much delay to the rendered image in my C++ program?
I am trying to achieve the following:

Grab Frames from my DeckLink Capture Card using the DeckLink SDK (1920 x 1080 @60 fps 8bit per channel frames)
Encode them using nvJPEG
Decode them again also using nvJPEG
Display them with close to no perceivable delay (For now I tried rendering them with SDL and OpenCV)

It might sound weird to encode and decode them right after, but I would like to evaluate the influences of the compression in an active user testing scenario.
I managed to create a solution that works, but when decoding is performed the resulting stream has a delay which is way higher than I would expect at approximately 2.2 seconds.
Below is an image of the source and the second monitor showing the frames rendered with sdl when my decoding function is called:

When I only perform encoding and the decoding function is commented out, the delay is approx 50ms:

To get a better understanding if it´s even possible in theory I did some investigations regarding speed of encoding and decoding.
For example I tried running my program only with encoding and writing the *.jpeg files to disk. I set up a counter and grabbed 3600 Frames, encoded them and saved them. Doing this I achieved 59.52 fps, which is basically the framerate at which the capture card is sending frames (60 fps).
At next I used the decoding example which NVIDIA provides in their cuda-samples repository to read and decode the 3600 frames. There I achieved a framerate of ~200 fps.
I also tried timing encoding & decoding aswell as the whole time it took from frame arrival to rendering of the frame.
When the decoding function is commented out, the ouput looks like this:
Time for encoding: 1.988256 ms
Time between frame arrival and display: 12.608000 ms
Time for encoding: 2.246624 ms
Time between frame arrival and display: 12.603800 ms
Time for encoding: 1.830784 ms
Time between frame arrival and display: 12.099000 ms

When the decoding function is called:
Time for encoding: 1.802432 ms
Time for decoding: 5.869888 ms
Time between frame arrival and display: 18.190200 ms
Time for encoding: 1.594944 ms
Time for decoding: 6.192608 ms
Time between frame arrival and display: 18.531900 ms
Time for encoding: 2.071168 ms
Time for decoding: 5.807488 ms
Time between frame arrival and display: 18.527200 ms

Here it looks like, when decoding only a delay of ~6ms is added compared to only encoding.
However when comparing that to the observed delay of more than 2 seconds, something does not add up.
So either my approach of timing this is wrong or there are some problems with how I am handling my decoding and displaying.
I think there might be issues with how I am allocating and managing memory, or in general how I am setting up my handlers and Callbacks.
I have also thought about creating different encoding and decoding buffers myself, so that, for example, the incoming "raw" frames are first written to a buffer and the encoding and decoding processes are detached from this. However, I'm not sure whether this will bring me advantages in terms of performance or whether it will only cause problems with timings and synchronization.
Any tips or hints?
Below is the code of my current program:
#include <DeckLinkAPI.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <nvjpeg.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <helper_cuda.h>

using namespace std;
using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using std::chrono::duration_cast;
using std::chrono::duration;
using std::chrono::milliseconds;

bool escapePressed = false;

int dev_malloc(void** p, size_t s) { return (int)cudaMalloc(p, s); }

int dev_free(void* p) { return (int)cudaFree(p); }

int host_malloc(void** p, size_t s, unsigned int f) { return (int)cudaHostAlloc(p, s, f); }

int host_free(void* p) { return (int)cudaFreeHost(p); }

class CUDAHandler {
public:
    CUDAHandler(int width, int height, int quality) : width(width), height(height), quality(quality) {
        
        checkCudaErrors(cudaGetDeviceProperties(&cuda_props, 0));

        printf("Using GPU %d (%s, %d SMs, %d th/SM max, CC %d.%d, ECC %s)\n",
            0, cuda_props.name, cuda_props.multiProcessorCount,
            cuda_props.maxThreadsPerMultiProcessor, cuda_props.major, cuda_props.minor,
            cuda_props.ECCEnabled ? "on" : "off");

        nvjpegDevAllocator_t dev_allocator = { &dev_malloc, &dev_free };
        nvjpegPinnedAllocator_t pinned_allocator = { &host_malloc, &host_free };
        int flags = 0;
        
        // nvJPEG handle and state
        checkCudaErrors(nvjpegCreateEx(NVJPEG_BACKEND_DEFAULT, &dev_allocator, &pinned_allocator, flags, &nvjpeg_handle));

        checkCudaErrors(nvjpegJpegStateCreate(nvjpeg_handle, &jpeg_state));
        // Encoder
        checkCudaErrors(nvjpegEncoderStateCreate(nvjpeg_handle, &encoder_state, cuda_stream));
        checkCudaErrors(nvjpegEncoderParamsCreate(nvjpeg_handle, &encoder_params, cuda_stream));
        checkCudaErrors(nvjpegEncoderParamsSetQuality(encoder_params, quality, cuda_stream));
        checkCudaErrors(nvjpegEncoderParamsSetSamplingFactors(encoder_params, NVJPEG_CSS_444, cuda_stream));

        checkCudaErrors(cudaStreamCreateWithFlags(&cuda_stream, cudaStreamNonBlocking));

        dev_malloc(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&d_rgb), width * height * 3);
        dev_malloc(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&d_decoded_rgb), width * height * 3);

        source.channel[0] = d_rgb;
        source.pitch[0] = width * 3;
        output.channel[0] = d_decoded_rgb;
        output.pitch[0] = width * 3;
    }

    ~CUDAHandler() {
        checkCudaErrors(nvjpegDestroy(nvjpeg_handle));
        checkCudaErrors(nvjpegJpegStateDestroy(jpeg_state));
        checkCudaErrors(cudaStreamDestroy(cuda_stream));
        checkCudaErrors(nvjpegEncoderStateDestroy(encoder_state));
        checkCudaErrors(nvjpegEncoderParamsDestroy(encoder_params));

        checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(d_rgb));
        checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(d_decoded_rgb));

    }

    void Encode(const unsigned char* rgb, vector<unsigned char>& jpeg_image) {
        checkCudaErrors(cudaStreamSynchronize(cuda_stream));
        cudaEvent_t startEvent = NULL, stopEvent = NULL;

        float loopTime = 0;
        
        checkCudaErrors(cudaEventCreate(&startEvent, cudaEventBlockingSync));
        checkCudaErrors(cudaEventCreate(&stopEvent, cudaEventBlockingSync));

        checkCudaErrors(cudaEventRecord(startEvent, cuda_stream));

        cudaMemcpy(d_rgb, rgb, width * height * 3, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        nvjpegEncodeImage(nvjpeg_handle, encoder_state, encoder_params, &source, NVJPEG_INPUT_RGBI, width, height, cuda_stream);
        nvjpegEncodeRetrieveBitstream(nvjpeg_handle, encoder_state, NULL, &bitstream_length, cuda_stream);
        jpeg_image.resize(bitstream_length);
        nvjpegEncodeRetrieveBitstream(nvjpeg_handle, encoder_state, jpeg_image.data(), &bitstream_length, cuda_stream);

        checkCudaErrors(cudaEventRecord(stopEvent, cuda_stream));
        checkCudaErrors(cudaStreamSynchronize(cuda_stream));
        cudaStreamSynchronize(cuda_stream);
        
        checkCudaErrors(cudaEventElapsedTime(&loopTime, startEvent, stopEvent));
        time = static_cast<double>(loopTime);
        printf("Time for encoding: %f ms\n", time);
    }

    void Decode(const unsigned char* jpeg_image, size_t jpeg_size, unsigned char* rgb) {
        checkCudaErrors(cudaStreamSynchronize(cuda_stream));
        cudaEvent_t startEvent = NULL, stopEvent = NULL;

        float loopTime = 0;

        checkCudaErrors(cudaEventCreate(&startEvent, cudaEventBlockingSync));
        checkCudaErrors(cudaEventCreate(&stopEvent, cudaEventBlockingSync));

        checkCudaErrors(cudaEventRecord(startEvent, cuda_stream));
        checkCudaErrors(nvjpegDecode(nvjpeg_handle, jpeg_state, jpeg_image, jpeg_size, NVJPEG_OUTPUT_RGBI, &output, cuda_stream));
        
        cudaMemcpy(rgb, d_decoded_rgb, width * height * 3, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

        checkCudaErrors(cudaEventRecord(stopEvent, cuda_stream));
        checkCudaErrors(cudaEventSynchronize(stopEvent));

        checkCudaErrors(cudaEventElapsedTime(&loopTime, startEvent, stopEvent));
        time = static_cast<double>(loopTime);
        printf("Time for decoding: %f ms\n", time);
    }

private:
    int width, height, quality;
    size_t bitstream_length;
    nvjpegHandle_t nvjpeg_handle;
    nvjpegJpegState_t jpeg_state;
    cudaStream_t cuda_stream;
    nvjpegEncoderState_t encoder_state;
    nvjpegEncoderParams_t encoder_params;
    nvjpegImage_t output;
    nvjpegImage_t source;
    unsigned char* d_rgb;
    unsigned char* d_decoded_rgb;
    cudaDeviceProp cuda_props;
    double time;

};

class MyDeckLinkCallback : public IDeckLinkInputCallback {
public:
    MyDeckLinkCallback(SDL_Renderer* renderer, SDL_Texture* texture, CUDAHandler* cudaHandler)
        : renderer(renderer), texture(texture), cudaHandler(cudaHandler), refCount(1), input_rgb_image(width* height * 3), jpeg_image(width* height * 3), output_rgb_image(width* height * 3) {}

    HRESULT VideoInputFrameArrived(IDeckLinkVideoInputFrame* videoFrame, IDeckLinkAudioInputPacket* audioPacket) override {
        if (videoFrame) {
            auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

            if (escapePressed) {
                printf("Escape key pressed, exiting program.\n");
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }

            void* frameBytes;
            videoFrame->GetBytes(&frameBytes);

            ConvertARGBToRGB(static_cast<unsigned char*>(frameBytes), input_rgb_image.data(), width, height);
            cudaHandler->Encode(input_rgb_image.data(), jpeg_image);
            cudaHandler->Decode(jpeg_image.data(), jpeg_image.size(), output_rgb_image.data());

            //SDL_UpdateTexture(texture, NULL, frameBytes, videoFrame->GetRowBytes());
            SDL_UpdateTexture(texture, nullptr, output_rgb_image.data(), width * 3);
            SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, nullptr, nullptr);
            SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

            auto t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
            duration<double, std::milli> ms_double = t2 - t1;
            printf("Time between frame arrival and display: %f ms\n", ms_double.count());
        }
        return S_OK;
    }

    HRESULT VideoInputFormatChanged(BMDVideoInputFormatChangedEvents notificationEvents, IDeckLinkDisplayMode* newDisplayMode, BMDDetectedVideoInputFormatFlags detectedSignalFlags) override {
        printf("Video format changed\n");
        return S_OK;
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppvObject) override {
        if (ppvObject == NULL)
            return E_POINTER;
        if (riid == IID_IUnknown) {
            *ppvObject = static_cast<IUnknown*>(this);
            AddRef();
            return S_OK;
        }
        if (riid == IID_IDeckLinkInputCallback) {
            *ppvObject = static_cast<IDeckLinkInputCallback*>(this);
            AddRef();
            return S_OK;
        }
        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }

    ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef() override {
        return InterlockedIncrement(&refCount);
    }

    ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release() override {
        ULONG newRefCount = InterlockedDecrement(&refCount);
        if (newRefCount == 0) {
            delete this;
        }
        return newRefCount;
    }

private:
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;
    SDL_Texture* texture;
    CUDAHandler* cudaHandler;
    ULONG refCount;

    int width = 1920;
    int height = 1080;
    std::vector<unsigned char> input_rgb_image;
    std::vector<unsigned char> jpeg_image;
    std::vector<unsigned char> output_rgb_image;

    void ConvertARGBToRGB(const unsigned char* argb, unsigned char* rgb, int width, int height) {
        cv::Mat argbImage(height, width, CV_8UC4, const_cast<unsigned char*>(argb));
        cv::Mat rgbImage;
        cv::cvtColor(argbImage, rgbImage, cv::COLOR_RGBA2RGB);
        std::memcpy(rgb, rgbImage.data, width * height * 3);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
        printf("Failed to initialize SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Video", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 1920, 1080, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (!window) {
        printf("Failed to create SDL window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    if (!renderer) {
        printf("Failed to create SDL renderer: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_BGR24, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, 1920, 1080);
    if (!texture) {
        printf("Failed to create SDL texture: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }

    CUDAHandler cudaHandler(1920, 1080, 90);

    IDeckLinkIterator* deckLinkIterator = NULL;
    HRESULT result = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CDeckLinkIterator, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IDeckLinkIterator, (void**)&deckLinkIterator);
    if (result != S_OK) {
        printf("Failed to create DeckLink iterator instance\n");
        SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }

    IDeckLink* deckLink = NULL;
    if (deckLinkIterator->Next(&deckLink) == S_OK) {
        IDeckLinkInput* deckLinkInput = NULL;
        result = deckLink->QueryInterface(IID_IDeckLinkInput, (void**)&deckLinkInput);
        if (result != S_OK) {
            printf("Failed to query DeckLink input interface\n");
            deckLinkIterator->Release();
            SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
            SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
            SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
            SDL_Quit();
            return 1;
        }

        MyDeckLinkCallback* callback = new MyDeckLinkCallback(renderer, texture, &cudaHandler);
        result = deckLinkInput->SetCallback(callback);
        if (result != S_OK) {
            printf("Failed to set DeckLink callback\n");
            deckLinkInput->Release();
            deckLinkIterator->Release();
            SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
            SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
            SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
            SDL_Quit();
            return 1;
        }

        result = deckLinkInput->EnableVideoInput(bmdModeHD1080p6000, bmdFormat8BitBGRA, bmdVideoInputFlagDefault);
        if (result != S_OK) {
            printf("Failed to enable video input\n");
            deckLinkInput->Release();
            deckLinkIterator->Release();
            SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
            SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
            SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
            SDL_Quit();
            return 1;
        }

        result = deckLinkInput->StartStreams();
        if (result != S_OK) {
            printf("Failed to start streams\n");
            deckLinkInput->Release();
            deckLinkIterator->Release();
            SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
            SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
            SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
            SDL_Quit();
            return 1;
        }

        bool quit = false;
        SDL_Event event;
        while (!quit) {
            while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
                if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                    quit = true;
                }
                else if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
                    if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE) {
                        escapePressed = true;
                        quit = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        deckLinkInput->StopStreams();
        deckLinkInput->Release();
        deckLinkIterator->Release();
        delete callback;
    }
    else {
        printf("No DeckLink device found\n");
    }

    CoUninitialize();

    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}


Edit
I have found that if I set parameters that speed up the encode and decode process, the delay is significantly less.
For example, if I perform 422 or 420 colorsampling in the encoding process, even with my decoding function I am in a delay range of ~4 frames as before with the version with the decoding function commented out.
The times that I measure for encoding and decoding are only slightly reduced.
So now I'm wondering if the delay is perhaps not caused by the decoding itself but perhaps in the process of copying between the memory of the graphics card and the PC.

Small nitpick, don't use std::chrono:: high_resolution_clock, it is just an alias for either steady_clock or system_clock, of which the choice is implementation defined. Don't let the compiler choose as you will get different results. Use explicitly in this case steady_clock.

^ Is usually just an alias. I've seen some interesting alternatives (though not in anything I'd consider "The Wild") but I'm with you. You have to KNOW what you're going to get before you use it and be comfortable with potential problems in the future if you port the code or your knowledge is rendered obsolete.

Are you using compiler optimisations? Is the delay constant or does it increase over time?

Hello, thanks for your fast replies!
As @Casey suggested I am now using steady_clock. The timings I am printing stay constant at ~18ms (They don´t increase over time).
@AlanBirtles For now I only ran it in Debug settings without any compiler optimisations. I tried it with some speed optimizations today, but the result was similar.
However in both cases, the delay did indeed increase over time, it starts at ~12 frames and increases fairly quickly until it remains constant at around 135 frames delay. (It reaches the delay of 135 roughly 20 seconds after starting the program)
